# jQuery Mobile objects stay in memory

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am currently developing a jQuery mobile app. On one page there is a chart created (highcharts) which then can be exported (canvg and canvas2ImagePlugin). However, I noticed that the chart object stays in memory. This has the effect that if the page is opened multiple times and the export button is then pressed, all the previously generated graphs will be exported. 
 
Having a look at Chrome Dev Tool's heap snapshot, I noticed that all the objects stay in memory. To demonstrate this, I made a very basic app on jsfiddle, leaving all the highchart and canvg code out: http://jsfiddle.net/dreischer/Lt4Xw/ --> just click on the button to go to the second page. If you click the export button a pop-up will open. However, if you go back to page one and then page two and click the button again, two pop-ups will open (you might need to allow pop-ups).

I also tried setting analyseGraph null or undefined or using .remove() on pagebeforehide but it didn't help.

Thank you for your help!

Here is the code, for this example: 
**HTML:**

```
 <div data-role="page" id="p1"> 
        <div  data-role="header"><h1>Header Page 1</h1></div> 
        <div  data-role="content">
            <p>Page 1</p>
            <a href="#p2" data-role="button">Go To Page 2</a>
        </div> 
    </div> 

    <div data-role="page" id="p2">
        <div  data-role="header" data-rel="back"><h1>Header Page 2</h1></div>
        <div  data-role="content">
            <p>Page 2</p>
            <a href="#p1" data-role="button">Go To Page 1</a>
            <a id="export_graph" data-role="button" style="max-width: 300px;" data-mini="true">Export</a>
        </div>    
    </div>
```

**Javascript**:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#p2', function (){

    var Graph = function (){
        this.drawGraph = function(){};
        this.exportCanvas = function(){
            window.open();
        };        
    }

    var analyseGraph = new Graph();
    analyseGraph.drawGraph();
     $(document).on('click', '#export_graph', function(){ 
        analyseGraph.exportCanvas();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you show page 2 you bind a click event to document. So I think you must use 'off' once in a while, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt4Xw/2/)

```
$(document).on('click', '#export_graph', function(){ 
    analyseGraph.exportCanvas();
    $(document).off('click');
});
```